# How to add an entry using Dbcontext

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext, pgadmin-4

I have a table in pgAdmin4 and I am trying to add data only to the hours and total_amount columns without altering any of the other data. The other data gets added on a different page and then the user is redirected to a new page where they are prompted to input the hours and click submit. With the click of the submit I want the user input to be loaded to the hour column. How would I do this using dbcontext?
This is the code I have tried:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int hours, int amount){

FacilityPriority facilityPriority = new FacilityPriority()
       {

NumberHours = hours,

TotalAmount = amount
 
}

await DbContext.FacilityPriority.AddAsync(facilityPriority);
            
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`
```

However this keeps erroring, I have also tried DbContext.Update and this also doesn't work.

Comment: `this keeps erroring` with what error? EF Core works. `SaveChangesAsync` works

Comment: Are you trying to add a record or update an existing record?

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be that intend to update an existing entity, but you aren't updating an entity, you are adding a new one, which is likely incomplete. When performing an update you want to provide enough information so the DbContext can find the entity to update and then adjust the expected values.

When you added a new FacilityPriority and after calling `SaveChanges` you should have been able to access the PK for that new record, I.e. FacilityPriorityId. It is important to send this ID to any view via the view-model for that view so that when posting back an update you can provide the PK to retrieve the record and update it's values:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int facilityPriorityId, int hours, int amount)
{
    var facilityPriorty = DbContext.FacilityPriority.Single(x => x.FacilityPriorityId == facilityPriorityId);
    facilityPriority.NumberHours = hours;
    facilityPriority.TotalAmount = amount;

    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When I try doing this my code errors on this line:                           var facilityPriorty = DbContext.FacilityPriority.Single(x => x.FacilityPriorityId == facilityPriorityId); with this error "InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" How do I fix this?

Comment: Then that means you have an Update call where there is no existing record. Check what the facilityPriorityId is when it comes in. If this is MVC and you are passing a value from a Model, check that it has been populated correctly when the page was loaded. If it's correct client side then check that your client code is resolving it correctly. (I.e. reading from the Model vs. data- attribute, etc. If you're method is the result of a form submit, make sure you have a @Html.HiddenFor declared for the Model's FacilityPriorityId.